# QTableView not scrollable and text is not wrapped

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I am trying to make something like QtCreator log window.
I am using QTableView with the following properties:
- one column, 
- `horisontalHeaderStretchLastSection = true`
- `horizontalHeaderVisible = false`
- `wordWrap = true`
- `autoScroll = true`
- `horizontalScrollBarPolicy = scrollBarAlwaaysOn`

And I use the following code to insert new row into the table

```
modelView = new QStandardItemModel;
modelView ->setColumnCount(1);
modelView ->setRowCount(0);
ui->tableView->setModel(modelView );

QString msg = "Test Messege 1...................................................................................................................................................................END";
QStandardItem *row = new QStandardItem(msg);
modelView ->setRowCount(window->rowCount()+1);
modelView ->setItem(window->rowCount()-1, 0, row);
```

However, Neither the text wraps, nor the view is scrollable horizontally, only the content that is within the window size appears.

I get the following view:

[image]

Comment: Start to remove horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection

Comment: @Fabio doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547363/458999

Needed to call `resizeRowsToContents` after each row insertion